# Refused to load the script because it violates the following Content Security Policy

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, reactjs

Refused to load the script 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive:

> `"script-src 'self'
>   'sha256-GgRxrVOKNdB4LrRsVPDSbzvfdV4UqglmviH9GoBJ5jk='". Note that
>   'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a
>   fallback.`

It's a google extension with react and node express. please help.

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Can you try the `code` from the `official` site. The `integrity` hash not matching could be the problem.